# exec classifier in spring-boot-maven-plugin in pom - pod startup error - Openshift

Tags: java, openshift, maven-2, redhat, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to push my microservice to nexus and at the same time deploy to openshift.

my pom has got this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <classifier>exec</classifier>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This results in the creation of two jar files at the time of build.

my-service-exec.jar
my-service.jar

I took the advice from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html and added the exec classifier in my pom

After deploy and at pod startup I see this error message:

```
ERROR Neither $JAVA_MAIN_CLASS nor $JAVA_APP_JAR is set and 2 JARs found in /deployments (1 expected)
```

and the pod is not starting.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the repackage goal will replace the original artifact with the repackaged one. That is a sane behaviour for modules that represent an app, but if your module is used as a dependency of another module, you need to provide a classifier for the repackaged one.

The reason for that is that application classes are packaged in `BOOT-INF/classes` so that the dependent module cannot load a repackaged jar's classes.
[spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html)